# Cannot read csv file Apache Zeppelin 0.8

Tags: csv, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I am currently using Apache Zeppelin 0.8. I tried loading a csv file like this :

```
val df = spark.read.option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").csv("/path/to/csv/name.csv")
```

I have also tried this :

```
val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").load("/path/to/csv/name.csv")
```

However, it fails printing out the following :

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Statistics.getThreadStatistics()Lorg/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem$Statistics$StatisticsData;

**NOTE THAT :**
Problem is **solved** **IF** I specify my own build for Spark using the SPARK_HOME env variable in *zeppelin-env.sh*. However, I would still like a solution to this that does not require me to do so, as I have a few other libraries that do not work with that version of Spark.

Comment: ZEPPELIN-3586 will fix this issue

Comment: I don't see how this is relevant as I am simply trying to load a csv from my local filesystem.

Comment: The issue is not specific to CSV files. Any `sc.textFile(...)` is throwing me that exception.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like effective classpath in spark runtime spark has a conflicting version of hadoop-fs library. It may be caused by your fat jar bringing an incompatible version.

If you open Spark UI in *Environment* tab you can see all the jar files on the classpath. There you can try to figure out which library is causing trouble.

If you're building a fat jar, try having a look into the contents of it to see whether it also contains Hadoop classes

```
jar -tf /path/to/your/jar | grep "org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem"
```

If it does you should mark your Hadoop dependencies in mvn/sbt as provided.